# is there a way that I can clear the broadcast of SMS_SENT or SMS_DELIVERED so that other apps won't get it?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, smsmanager

I am looking for a potential hack in my application where I am unable to get the onReceive() or SMS_SENT or SMS_DELIVERED in devices like Oppo, Vivo, Mi.

A message is sent from my device and I register a receiver to listen for the status of the message, sent and delivered, after that, I will do some networking calls.

Currently, my app is unable to get the onReceive(). Why? Because I add value to an Array every time my onReceive() gets called and send to the server. I am getting an Empty Array for devices like Oppo, Vivo, Mi.

How can I track this this or at least reproduce it?

Is there an app or any setting that could delete or cancel the broadcast and prevent reaching my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm, so it is not calling onReceive or the Intent data parameter is returning null of the onReceive method? Can you try the following?

[Send SMS until it is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083158/send-sms-until-it-is-successful)

Comment: My onReceive is not getting called. There are two receivers, one for SMS_SENT and other for SMS_DELIVERED. In SMS_SENT if the resultcode is not Result_OK then I am adding it to array(which is send to server), In SMS_DELIVERED, I am adding to the array for each case like( Result_OK and Result_Canceled). So, in Logs I checked that I am getting array Empty.  I think I might get REsult_OK in SMS_SENT and I am not getting SMS_DELIVERED receiver or onReceive is not getting called.

" the Intent data parameter is returning null " is this possible in SMS_SENT and SMS_DELIVERED?

Comment: Can you try to put debugger in the receive and see what you are getting? Also please make sure services are already declared in the manifest file.